# AudioKit-Oscillator starts with click-sound, the first time it is started

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, audiokit

I got the problem, that the DynamicOscillator() is making a click-sound the first time it is used after the app is started. It sounds just like if the fade-in doesn't work, but I don't get why.

Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI
import AVFoundation
import AudioKit
import SoundpipeAudioKit

struct Exercise1View: View {
    
    let osc = DynamicOscillator() //Oscillator from AudioKit
    let audioEngine = AudioEngine()
    
    var body: some View {
        Button {
            osc.setWaveform(Table(.sine)) // set osc-type to sine-wave
            osc.$frequency.ramp(to: 440, duration: 0) // set frequency of osc
            osc.amplitude = 0 // set amplitude to 0
            osc.start()
            osc.$amplitude.ramp(to: 1, duration: 0.01) //fade in, so there is no click sound
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) { // wait 1 second
                osc.$amplitude.ramp(to: 0, duration: 0.01) //fade out, so there is no click sound
            }
        } label: { Text("play tone") }
        .onAppear {
            audioEngine.output = osc
            do {
                try audioEngine.start()
            } catch {
                print("could not start audioengine")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you have any idea, please let me know. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Set the oscillator amplitude to zero on init and then start it when you start the audio engine.

```
struct Exercise1View: View {

    let osc = DynamicOscillator(amplitude: 0) // Set amplitude to zero here
    let audioEngine = AudioEngine()

    var body: some View {
        Button {
            osc.setWaveform(Table(.sine)) 
            osc.$frequency.ramp(to: 440, duration: 0)
            osc.$amplitude.ramp(to: 1, duration: 0.01) 
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1.0) {
                osc.$amplitude.ramp(to: 0, duration: 0.01) 
            }
        } label: { Text("play tone") }
        .onAppear {
            audioEngine.output = osc
            do {
                osc.start() // Start Oscillator right away, manage playback with amplitude
                try audioEngine.start()
            } catch {
                print("could not start audioengine")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, unfortunately the error persists when I try your solution. Is an oscillator supposed to be used that way (managing the playback with amplitude)?

Comment: There wasn't any error in either solution. The fade In didn't work in one and does in the other.  The oscillator does what an oscillator does, there is no way its "supposed" to be used. Make it do what you want. You can also since it through the amplitude envelope to achieve this effect. Maybe that's what you're after.

Comment: Are you sure the fade In does work in your solution? I am talking only about the first fade In after the app is started. Somehow it is still clicking when I try your approach. @Aurelius

Comment: I only tried in the simulator...